# Cost of bringing dead body from France to India

Tags: france, indian-citizens, india

My cousin died in a car accident in France a day ago. We are from India. He went to France for higher studies 3 years ago and was an Indian citizen.

Can anyone please tell us what will be the approximate cost in Euros of bringing his dead body from France to India so that we can do his last rites in India?

Comment: Sorry for your loss. This is one of the first link that comes when searching in France for funeral repatriation: https://www.eclips.aero/en/ (I have no relation to this company).